# AS3 FacebookMobile apprequest

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

I have this adobe air project using Facebook application, and I used to send feed to friends walls sharing this application, then Facebook disabled this feature of posting on your friend's wall via Facebook graph, so I need now to send application request using "FacebookMobile" library.

Any help, greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: 1. Show us your codes; 2. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too urgent to fix that issue, haven't found any solution on flex regarding the issue, so I created a native extension on iOS concerning Facebook and used it in my project , so now I can open a view with application requests plus defining the users to send to.

Thanks